# Iterate ArrayList in for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that makes of a `ArrayList` in vba. I try to iterate through it, using `for` loop, but I get an error. I'm not sure what use as a `LBound` and `UBound` and I can't use either of those functions on the `ArrayList`.

```
Function test(dataArray() As Double)

    Dim i As Long


    Dim arr As Object
    Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For i = LBound(dataArray) To UBound(dataArray)
        arr.Add dataArray(i)
    Next

    arr.Sort

    For i = 1 To arr.Count
       If arr(i) <= 10000 Then 'error
          ...
       End If
    Next

End Function
```

I get a `index out of range, index must be positive and should not exceed the collection's size` error inside the cycle. How would I iterate through the `ArrayList` without errors inside `for` cycle?

Comment: `arr` starts counting with `0` therefore it should be `For i = 0 To arr.Count -1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

collection starts at 0 not at 1. Here is a correction

```
For i = 0 To arr.Count-1
       If arr(i) <= 10000 Then 'error
          ...
       End If
    Next
```